# A not compact operator defined in $l^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

I'm trying to solve the following problem presented in Kreyszig's Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications. Consider the operator $T:l^2\to l^2$ defined by
$$Tx = (\alpha_k\xi_k), \quad x=(\xi_k)\in l^2,$$
where the sequence $(\alpha_k)$ is dense in $[0,1]$. I have to prove that $T$ is not compact, so I consider the bounded sequence $(e_n)$ given by
$$e_n = (0,0,\ldots,1_n,0,0,\ldots).$$
We then obtain the sequence $(Te_n)$ given by
$$Te_n = (0,0,\ldots,\alpha_n,0,0,\ldots).$$

I don't know how to justify that $(Te_n)$ doesn't have a convergent subsequence, or even worse if this sequence is the appropiate to proceed. In the solution given, the author says "every $\alpha_k$ is an eigenvalue of $T$" (so you can apply a result that every sequence of eigenvalues of a compact operators must converge to zero and obtain a contradiction) but that clearly is not correct.

I would appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Comment: $Te_n$ does have a convergent subsequence converging to $0$, because you just choose the sequence $Te_{n_k}$ where $n_1<n_2<\dots$ such that $\alpha_{n_k}\to 0$ (we can do that since $(\alpha_n)$ is dense in $[0,1]$).  You need to cut $Te_n$ down to something that avoids this.

Comment: There are infinitely many $k$ with $\alpha_k>1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way of proving this is to use the theorem which says that any compact operator on a Hilbert space has at most countbaly many eigen values which, if infinite in number, form a sequence tending to $ 0$. Note that $Te_n=\alpha_n e_n$ so each $\alpha_i$ is an eigen value.  But if the $\alpha_i$'s form a  sequence tending to $0$ they cannot be dense in $[0,1]$.

Comment: It was in front of me and I didn't notice it. It was so simple. Thanks, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also proceed with the same idea in your original proof without referring to the spectral theory of compact operators:

Since $\alpha_n$ is bounded and not tending to zero, there is a subsequence $n_k$ with $\alpha_{n_k}\to c\ne0$. Now the sequence $e_{n_k}$ is bounded, and its image sequence $Te_{n_k}$ has no convergent subsequence. Indeed, if it would have a convergent subsequence $Te_{n_{k_\ell}}\to y$ then its limit $y$ would have to be $0$ (why?), but $\alpha_{n_{k_\ell}}\to c\ne0$, a contradiction (why?).